# Trying to send a POST request using the body of a GET request

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on a project to create API routes for two third party applications to communicate with one another using NodeJS/express. The issue I am having is that I am trying to have third party application A (3PA) get a list of timeslots from a calendar in third party application B (3PB) and then send a message to a user in 3PB containing those timeslots.

The route looks like this:

```
router.post('/request_appointment_times', function(req, res){
**google sheets api logic**

async function gsrun(client){
    **getting data from google sheet**
        
        var request = require('request');
        require('request-debug')(request);
        var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': '3PB API URL',
        'headers': {
            'accept' : '*/*',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + apiKey,
            'content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
        
        };

        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            //console.log(response.body);
            else
            res.json({"message": "It Works!",});
            slotsList = new String(response.body.slots);
            slotsListArr = slotsList.split(',');
            var rnd = Math.random(0, slotsListArr.length);
            ssn.providedSlots = slotsListArr[rnd];
            ssn.providedSlots2 = slotsListArr[rnd];
            if (ssn.providedSlots == ssn.providedSlots2) {
               ssn.providedSlots2 = ssn.slotsListArr[rnd]
            }
            if (ssn.providedSlots == ssn.providedSlots2) {
              ssn.providedSlots2 = ssn.slotsListArr[rnd]
            }    
            console.log(providedSlots);
            console.log(providedSlots2);
        });
}
});
```

Currently, I can't even get the providedSlots to print as the request function won't communicate with the console. My question is, is it possible/how can I do a POST to 3PB using the response body from my GET request within this same route. I apologize if I worded this poorly or didn't provide enough information. Any help is much appreciated and if I need to provide additional information let me know!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of this you are defining `gsrun` in your route handler but aren't actually invoking it. Should be more like this:

```
function gsrun() { /* logic */ }

router.post('/request_appointment_times', function(req, res){
    gsrun();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think that Node invokes the function automatically though, I have written tons of other routes in the same project this way without invoking gsrun and they all work and this route performs the google sheet functionality and the get request within gsrun, it just wont store the request.response.body for me to use later. If it provides any insight, I tried declaring another var options2 with a put request within the else of the request(options) but it throws the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client